# Using a Batch File to make simple Y/N questions. Problematic Code. HALP

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is the code I am having issues with. I need to execute the choice lines properly by sending to their respected classes (cls). All of the errors are with the ERRORLEVEL and choice scripts. This is the only main issue I have but if you can help by pointing out others then I would be thankful. Best wishes, Mystikality.

```
cls
@echo off
echo Welcome to the Alpha PPFI Program V0.001.
GOTO T1

:T1 
echo This is a security program ran just by a simple Batch file.
GOTO T2

:T2
echo If you have an interest in our program, enter your response below. 
GOTO Variable

:Variable
CHOICE /C YN /N /M "Welcome, if you would wish to continue, enter Y/N
below."
if %errorlevel%==Y GOTO Create
if %errorlevel%==N GOTO ExitWarning
:Create
CHOICE /C YN /N /M "Create a new PPFI interface? Y/N"
if %errorlevel%==Y GOTO BatchGen
if %errorlevel%==N GOTO Variable

:BatchGen
start call CreatePPFI_V0.001.bat
exit
pause

:ExitWarning
CHOICE /C YN /N /M "Are you sure you want to exit V0.001 PPFI interface
alpha? Y/N"
if %errorlevel%==Y GOTO Variable
if %errorlevel%==N GOTO exit'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check errorlevel to be 1 (first choice, "Y") or 2 (second choice, "N")

For example

```
if %errorlevel%==1 GOTO Create
if %errorlevel%==2 GOTO ExitWarning
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? Any specifics?

Comment: THANKS FOR THE HELP :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check errorlevel as other poster says. However their method won't work. `If errorlevel` tests for that number OR HIGHER. So reverse their lines or do it in a position independent way.

```
if errorlevel=1 if not errorlevel=2 Echo Error level is 1 exactly
```

See `choice /?` and `if /?` for help.

Comment: Nope, you're thinking of `if errorlevel 1`, etc. When you use `%errorlevel%`, it gets treated like a regular variable.

Comment: I assumed you were using `if` correctly, you aren't. There is a reson for `if errorlevel` as that is the standard way to test THAT WILL ALLWAYS WORK. So instead of order we have may be overwritten by any program. So it won't work on all systems.

Comment: If the user is stupid enough to overwrite a system variable, they deserve to have their code fail.

Comment: It's any program, any of the millions of programmers. Their names lend themselves to duplication. If one can't control a thing, don't use it (unless forced to).